Why use properties in conjunction with a field?
I recently started learning C# and just reached the topic of 'Properties'.
I understand the 'old' way of using a private field with an extra getter and setter function is a bit cumbersome and 'ugly'.
CarWithFields carWithFields = new CarWithFields();
carWithFields.setPrice(100);
Console.WriteLine(carWithFields.getPrice());

class CarWithFields
{
    private int _price;

    public int getPrice()
    {
        return _price;
    }

    public void setPrice(int value)
    {
        _price = value;
    }
};

Achieving the same thing with properties is much cleaner.
CarWithProperties carWithProperties = new CarWithProperties();
carWithProperties.Price = 100;
Console.WriteLine(carWithProperties.Price);

class CarWithProperties
{
    public int Price { get; set; }
}

However I have seen quite a lot of examples where both are used at the same time, with the property being used as a sort of 'wrapper' around the field?
CarWithBoth carWithBoth = new CarWithBoth();
carWithBoth.Price = 100;
Console.WriteLine(carWithBoth.Price);

class CarWithBoth
{
    private int _price;
    public int Price 
    { 
        get 
        {
            return _price;
        }

        set
        {
            _price = value;
        }
    }
}

I guess the third solution still looks better and cleaner than the first solution, but at that point why not just solely use a property? Is there any benefit to mixing these two approaches like this?

That old way you wrote is not "with properties", it's "with a getter and setter method" - properties are subtly different. Probably written be a reformed Java programmer who managed to sitch the language but not the habits! :D

The "'wrapper' around the field"-approach in your example doesn't make much sense. But if you would do something else in the get- or set-accessor, you needed it. So not every property is as simple that it returns/assigns a value.

"Under the hood" it always is "the old way". (Auto-) Properties are just syntactic sugar. You can actively choose to do all of it manually, but why would you?

Can you show some of the examples you have seen?

^^ that said: if you come across explicitly coded get/set methods: best to ask the original author if they didn't bother to document their reasoning behind surprising design decisions.

The last example could be very old code from before when auto properties got introduced in C# 3.0

Is there any benefit to mixing these two approaches like this? - There is often a mix of approaches, but they all become the same thing in the end as the shorter approach is expanded to the long approach by the compiler on your behalf. It gets even simpler with things like records, where you have record Car(int price, string Make, string Model) - the compiler writes the proeprties, the constructor, the code that compares two cars based on equality of all data items...

C# mostly evolves nowadays by finding more terse ways of doing what it can already do. public int Price => _price; is a short way of writing public int Price { get { return _price; } } etc. Chiefly you write the shortest code that still solves the problem. If you wanted extra code like public int Price{ get { if(_price == 0) throw new Exception("The price for this car is awaiting determination") else return _price; } set { if(value < 0) throw new Exception("Price cannot be negative") else _price = value; } } then you have to write it out i.e. make the custom logic the compiler can't do

"C# mostly evolves nowadays by finding more terse ways of doing what it can already do." and depending on the feature, it will actually be just rewritten as "the old way" in a process called "lowering". You can see that in (for example) sharplab.io. => https://sharplab.io/#v2:CYLg1APgAgTAjAWAFBQMwAJboMLoN7LpGYZRwAM6AsgJ4AKATgPYAO+6A5gKYAuA3OgDOvAQF9kooA==

Good point about sharplab.. it's a site that takes your code, compiles it, then decompiles it so you can see "what code did the compiler write for me" ? Take a look at https://sharplab.io/#v2:D4AQTAjAsAUOAEBhAhgJwOoEsAuALAyrgParYCCAdgCYAyRFA5gAqpEAOAzrAN6zz/w2qTADdk2AKbxMFbPAD6QzAGMJAbj4CQAZmmz4LFVM39u8EwP4MJci5d4xLTrQHYFS1RsfP4AX1h2Ahw2gaahTorCqvAAvPBiADYArurh/t786ZYWOvAgEAAM8ACyyADWUtzW2GrBNVkCOboARkRECfAAkhxkAEJoDMgysQB8BlFSADzwhQVe6bCoEsokVEhoAErLqwAUMnKGqgA08PjYwowl5RIAlGpAA

The Price property wan't touched, the Make property became a a "long way", the IsABargain property became a read-only "long way".. Take a look at the amount of code the compiler wrote for you turning that record into a class that knows how to compare itself to other instances of itself etc. Look also, at how the private backing field (the equivalent of your _price) for the Make became called <Make>k__BackingField - something you cannot type yourself as a name (because of the <>) - this never conflicts with a name you pick in your own code. You use <> in code for different reasons

The simple answer is, you need a backing field when you want to do something in an accessor or setter other than simply return or set a value, respectively.
Probably the most common example is an implementation of INotifyPropertyChanged, where you need to raise an event when a property is changed so subscribers (usually a UI component) can act accordingly:
public class ObservableObject : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private string _SomeProperty;
    public string SomeProperty
    {
        get
        {
            return _SomeProperty;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_SomeProperty == value)
                return;
            _SomeProperty = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(SomeProperty));
        }
    }

    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}

Another common use is the "lazy constructor" pattern where you have a read-only property that you only want to instantiate when and if it's needed:
    private object _someObject;
    public object SomeOtherObject
    {
        get
        {
            return _someObject ?? (_someObject = new object());
        }
    }

